# how to make batch file not readable but executable?

Tags: batch-file

I have automated a task. and I have to share batch file with team and other vendors. I want my script to be not readable but script should execute. How to achieve this?

Comment: No you cannot, closest is to use [bat2exe](https://www.bat2exe.net/) but it is not fool proof as it can still be extracted. You can always write a proper program using C and compile it to a proper executable.

Comment: Windows command processor `cmd.exe` must read the batch file (script) or it cannot be processed (executed) by `cmd.exe`. A bat to exe "converter" is not really a solution. All those "converters" just pack the batch file into an executable which extracts the batch file into (a subdirectory of) `%TEMP%` and execute `cmd.exe` to process the batch file. A user can press Ctrl+C while batch file is executed and `cmd.exe` halts execution and asks the user if the batch file execution should be really exited. This gives the user the time to copy the batch file from `%TEMP%` to any other directory.

Comment: @Mofi yes, or you can just right click and extract from the `.exe`

Comment: @Mofi, I searched everywhere. But it seems there is **no** any answer for this question.

Comment: There is an answer for this question: It is not possible to protect any script file for being read by a user because of the script interpreter needs to read the script file content, too. That is an answer, but not the answer you would like to get on your question.

Comment: What is the solution then? in my case i want users to be able to kick off a java program by executing a bat script located on a remote server. The java program handles all error logging while processing the 1000s of records that work. Once processing has completed we fix the rest and reprocess. My problem is hiding the pw (sure most if all wont have the knowledge to create a RDP session but its still a risk) but I also dont want to compile using a 3rd party because i dont have experience. Ideas? i can simply click the button for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting a bunch of `goto`s everywhere.
Also, try obscuring the variables with said `goto`s

```
::variable======================
set "password=hidden"

::add gotos=====================
:kkkkk
set password=h
goto jadvb
:jadvb
set password=%password%i
goto paosd
:paosd
set password=%password%d
goto alsmm
:alsmm
set password=%password%d
goto amdww
:amdww
set password=%password%e
goto njaww
:njaww
set password=%password%n
goto asdawds
:asdawds
::scramble======================
goto kkkkk

:amdww
set password=%password%e
goto njaww
:paosd
set password=%password%d
goto alsmm
:njaww
set password=%password%n
goto asdawds
:jadvb
set password=%password%i
goto paosd
:kkkkk
set password=h
goto jadvb
:alsmm
set password=%password%d
goto amdww

:asdawds
```

This won't make the file unreadable but it will obscure it greatly.

Comment: Care to explain how that should prevent me from reading the code (or the password in this case)?

Comment: I added some variable scrambling to help.
It won't work perfectly but it should be unreadable to any human without lots of thought and effort.

Comment: All scrambling and obfuscation doesn't help, when all I need to do is just `echo %password%` (btw: I can indeed resemble the password by just reading the code. Why do you produce it twice?)

Comment: I made three different steps.
The steps are separate programs.
I'm sorry if that wasn't made clear.